# Map drive from windows to linux file share

Tags: linux, windows, networking, cloud, drive

What I would like to do is to fire up a linux based cloud computer and be able to map a network drive from a local windows computer to this remote linux cloud computer. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, yes, presenting data from a local system to a remote one is doable.

But you'll need to provide much more information on what exactly you're trying to do for us to be able to provide specific assistance - start by looking at setting up a VPN to your cloud provider and SMB drivers for mounting the share in your Linux system.

Comment: Thank you, instead of going the easy route and just closing the question, you answered it by giving me a few things to look into so that I have a chance to develop an attempted solution.